# bug in bash sort with different columns?

Tags: bash, sorting, multiple-columns, cut

I am working with a file that contains 3 values, an ID (they happen to be protein ids in case you are curious), a value, and then another value. It is tab delimited, so it looks like this:

```
A2M     0.979569315988908       1
AACS    0.925340159491081       1
AAGAB   0.982296215686199       1
AAK1    0.736903840140103       1
AAMP    0.00589711816127862     0.138868449447202
AARS2   1       1
AARS    3.13300124295614e-05    0.00212792325492566
AARSD1  0.527417792161261       1
AASDH   0.869909252023668       1
AASDHPPT        0.763918221284724       1
AATF    0.691907759125663       1
ABAT    0.989693691462661       1
ABCA1   0.601194017450064       1
ABCA5   1       1
ABCA6   1       1
```

I am interested in sorting these IDs in alphabetical order and extracting various values. However, I noticed that sort sorts the IDs differently, depending on what I am extracting. When I execute:

```
    cut --fields\=1,2 input.txt|sort --key=1
```

The resulting file is:

```
A2M     0.979569315988908
AACS    0.925340159491081
AAGAB   0.982296215686199
AAK1    0.736903840140103
AAMP    0.00589711816127862
AARS2   1
AARS    3.13300124295614e-05 
AARSD1  0.527417792161261
AASDH   0.869909252023668
AASDHPPT        0.763918221284724
AATF    0.691907759125663
ABAT    0.989693691462661
ABCA1   0.601194017450064
ABCA5   1
ABCA6   1
```

BUT When I execute:

```
cut --fields\=1,3 input.txt|sort --key=1
```

I get

```
A2M     1
AACS    1
AAGAB   1
AAK1    1
AAMP    0.138868449447202
AARS    0.00212792325492566
AARS2   1
AARSD1  1
AASDH   1
AASDHPPT        1
AATF    1
ABAT    1
ABCA1   1
ABCA5   1
ABCA6   1
```

Notice that the positions of AARS and AARS2 are switched, which they shouldn't be since I am just sorting based on the first column. I've never seen any behavior like this from sort, and I've been using bash for a while now. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: can't reproduce that here with cut/sort v8.21. I get aars->aars2 with both 1,2 and 1,3

Comment: You don't need to escape (or even use) the `=` in the call to `cut`.

Comment: This is incredible I actually have reproduced this but don't believe it.

Comment: @MarcB I have sort sort (GNU coreutils) 8.4 and cut cut (GNU coreutils) 8.4
@shellter when I add -t="\t" to sort I get "error sort: multi-character tab `=\\t'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--key=1` option tells `sort` to use all "fields" from the first through the end of the line to sort the input.  As @rici observed first, by default this is a locale-sensitive sort, and in many locales whitespace is ignored for collation purposes.  That's what seems to be happening here.

If you want to sort *only* on the protein IDs, then that would be this:

```
cut --fields=1,2 input.txt | sort --key=1,1
cut --fields=1,3 input.txt | sort --key=1,1
```

@rici explains how to approach the problem by specifying a collation order that accounts for whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a locale-aware sort (which is the default). In many locales, whitespace is explicitly ignored in the collation order; that, combined with the fact that your key extends from the first field to the end of the line (which means that the `--key` option is redundant), effectively means that the lines are sorted as though the fields were concatenated without intervening whitespace.

There's a much longer explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27951508/1566221

My preference is to use `LC_COLLATE=C sort ...` for a non-locale-aware sort. (For example, define `alias csort="LC_COLLATE=C sort"`). In this case you could also just explicitly terminate the sort key by using `-k1,1`. If your first columns are unique, then that is sufficient.

Comment: Good observation about the effect of locale-awareness.  You are quite right that choosing collation according to the C locale also resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that sort is skips tabs... the net effect is that AARS0.00212792325492566 comes before AARS21 but AARS21 comes before AARS3.13300124295614e-05.  See [this quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037365/unix-sort-with-tab-delimiter).

The following should work

```
cut -f1,2 input.txt | sort -t$'\t'
```

Unfortunately it doesn't but I think this stripping out of tabs is what is causing the issue.

Comment: This did not fix it. cut -f1,2 input.txt | sort -t$'\t' produced different output then cut -f1,3 input.txt | sort -t$'\t'

Comment: The tabs are definitely what is doing it.